# Entity Framework - one to one optional relationship with same table

Tags: .net, entity-framework

.NET Entity Framework.
How can i create an optional 1:1 relationship to the same table? (a post can have a parent post)

I have defined it like this:
Post model:

```
  public int id { get; set; }
  public string name  { get; set; }
  [ForeignKey("parent_post")]
  public int? id_parent { get; set; }

  public virtual Post parent_post { get; set; }
  [InverseProperty("parent_post")]
  public virtual Post child_post { get; set; }
```

and then in fluent:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
     .HasOptional(b => b.parent_post)
     .WithOptionalDependent(b => b.child_post);
```

This "seems" to be working, but is this the correct way?

Comment: The way is correct if it is working. If somebody else offer you another way how do you know if it correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

for people who are trying to have self-reference relationship (one-to-many). it is simple as that.

```
public class Post
    {
        public Post()
        {
            Child = new HashSet<Post>();
        }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name  { get; set; }

    public Post ParentPost { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Post> ChildrenPosts { get; set; }

    }
```